# Полиморфизм в отображении элементов

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, avalonia

Если у контейнера (`ListBox`, `TreeView` и т.д.) `ItemsSource` принимает группу элементов, которые могут относиться к разным классом, как я могу создавать им различное представление? Например, у меня есть `ObservableCollection<Animal>`, при этом там могут содержаться экземпляры классов `Cat`, `Dog` и т.д. У кого-то может быть свойство с размахом крыльев, у кого-то с высотой прыжка, все это, естественно, не содержится в базовом классе `Animal`.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            <!-- здесь содержимое должно быть типозависимым -->
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Я не понимаю, как ItemTemplate может проверять на соответствие классу, выводя необходимые поля, которые могут различаться у разных классов. Если бы в XAML были условные блоки, то дело бы обстояло проще (как мне кажется).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/apps/design/controls/data-template-selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать коллекцию `DataTemplates` для установки соответствия `ViewModel` и `View`, например у `ListBox` (можно и у `UserControl`):

```
<ListBox.DataTemplates>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CatViewModel}">
    <vw:CatView/>
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DogViewModel}">
    <vw:DogView/>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.DataTemplates>
```

Для самого `ListBox` `ItemTemplate` тогда не нужно устанавливать.

Comment: А если вместо CatViewModel и DogViewModel указывать Cat и Dog, то это будет считаться нарушением, т.к View обращается напрямую к модели?

Comment: По-хорошему да, особенно в случае двусторонней привязки

Comment: Спасибо, это решает мою проблему!